# C# MS VS WebReference type of variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl

I would like to read a values from one webservice (here is [WSDL](http://adisrws.mfcr.cz/adistc/axis2/services/rozhraniCRPDPH.rozhraniCRPDPHSOAP)).

My code is here:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ahoj = new string[] { 28156609.ToString() };
    InformaceOPlatciType[] platceinfo;

    mfcrDPH.rozhraniCRPDPH srv = new mfcrDPH.rozhraniCRPDPH();
    StatusType status = srv.getStatusNespolehlivyPlatce(ahoj, out platceinfo);

    for (int i = 0; i < platceinfo.Length; i++)
   {
        mfcrDPH.InformaceOPlatciType info = platceinfo[i];
        Label1.Text = info.dic;
        Label2.Text = info.nespolehlivyPlatce;
   }
}
```

mfcrDPH is WebReference inside MS Visual Studio.

Problem is with value **info.nespolehlivyPlatce**. Value **info.dic** works fine. I don´t understand how to fix it, because inside WSDL I see that both variabels are principali same - type of both is *simple*.

For label2.Text I got an error:

> Error 3   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'mfcrDPH.NespolehlivyPlatceType' to
>   'string'  D:\Tvorba\vs2010\WebTelefony\DPH\DHP_Dash2.aspx.cs  27  27  WebTelefony

Here is picture with graphical information: [Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ye24.png)

Is possible to help me resolve why I got this type of error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error and try to understand it. This code:

```
Label2.Text = info.nespolehlivyPlatce;
```

Tries to assign an object of type `NespolehlivyPlatceType` to a property of type `string`, which are incompatible. So that's not going to work.

You need to find a property on the `NespolehlivyPlatceType` type which you can use. Expand the `simpleType` in your XSD/WSDL, use IntelliSense or check the Object Browser to see which properties are available on that class that are strings, or convertable to it. For example:

```
Label2.Text = info.nespolehlivyPlatce.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you! I found that it is enum, so I used ,,Label2.Text = (string)info.nespolehlivyPlatce.ToString();" and now is works.

Comment: That will just give you the name of the type, not that useful.

Comment: It got me status of item which I putted. Strange, but it works.

Comment: Then perhaps it's an enum.

Comment: Now I converted this code into VB and I found that in VB is possible read value only with Label2.Text = info.nespolehlivyPlatce.ToString(). I love VB for that simplicity

Answer (score 0):

The error message is being generate by a type mismatch. In the Wsdl the document is using tns (this name space) referring to a type other than a string. This is why in your code you see a type conversion error. You either need to change your type from a string to match the wsql type or you need to do some casting or conversion of type